# How to programmatically disable iOS 8 video capture in Mac Yosemite?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, ios8, osx-yosemite

Apple released a new feature allowing movie recording via QuickTime player. All you need to do is to connect the iOS 8 device to a Mac Yosemite machine, run QuickTime and set the connected device as the source of the movie. 
(Like explained here: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/)

I would like to prevent QuickTime to record a movie while my application is running. Any idea how can I do that?

Any value I can change in plist? Any special event I can listen to? Any other creative way to disrupt this process?

Thanks!

Nili

Comment: Switch your question to [Apple Stack](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question belongs here @Thomas.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Tweak quicktime seems not about programing to me... But that's just my humble opinion :)

Comment: It's not about tweaking. The question asks specifically about **plist** and **events**.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not asking how to tweak quicktime. I'm asking if there's some way to disable MY APP from broadcasting to this streaming. Please refer to the last line in my question and cancel your downvote.

Comment: @Nili I didn't downvote you. If one day I downvote you, I would write it in the comment with a -1 and a correct explanation. You're right this question belongs here.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, BTW I also posted my question in Apple Stack thanks to you (wasn't aware it exists!)

Comment: I found a trick for this Question. See my Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38737416/4390666

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's Developer Technical Support, it is not possible to opt your apps out of screen capture :\  Time to file an enhancement request I guess.