# How to prevent recording of iOS screen using quicktime

Tags: ios, screenshot, quicktime

So with iOS 8, we can now record the screen of iOS devices. I've searched extensively and cannot find a way to detect, let alone prevent, this recording. The app I'm working on deals with some potentially sensitive information and images and would like to prevent this if at all possible.

Thank you in advance for your responses and insights!

Anthony

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669636/how-to-programmatically-disable-ios-8-video-capture-in-mac-yosemite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there *is some way* to detect whether a display or QuickTime streaming is connected, because the Netflix app will show an error when that is the case (which also means you can't just use an iOS device and stream to your computer to watch it in big). The app works perfectly if QuickTime streaming is off with the cable is plugged in.

Maybe it just detects whether an external display is connected, and screen recording behaves like that, so basically you might have some success [with these APIs and notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html).

Also, you could use an [encrypted HTTP Live Stream according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1891/_index.html) which would be blacked out in the stream / the recording.