# iOS detect/block screen recording using QuickTime player

Tags: ios, quicktime, screen-recording

I want to block screen recording or video output per my app using QuickTime Player.

I had detected hdmi output and airplay with `UIScreen`.
But QuickTime Player video recording was no detect.

How to detect QuickTime Player?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thus don't know detect QuickTime Player recording.

But I Found a solution with some trick.

If QuickTime Player recording is running, AVAudioSession's output portType has been changed to HDMIOutput.

So I coding as follows...(Swift 2.2)

```
func checkOutputPortType() {
    let asRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    for output in asRoute.outputs {
        if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHDMI {
            // something you want..
        }
    }
}
```

Insert that function in ViewDidLoad and added `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkOutputPortType), name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With iOS 11 you can use the notification

```
NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange
```

on `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkIFScreenIsCapture), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil) ......
```

use selector

```
func checkIFScreenIsCapture(notification:Notification){
    guard let screen = notification.object as? UIScreen else { return }
    if screen.isCaptured == true {

    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work with AppKit/MacOS, any ideas?